# how to input command from terminal to interactive with python app in debug mode when using PyCharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Now I am debbuging a terminal interactive app write with Python 3, when I start the debugger, the app UI shows, but the app was interactive in terminal, for example, when we input `i` in terminal, the app should parse the `i` command as `information` then do some responsive action. But when the app was started as debug mode in Intellij Idea, I could not input anything in Intellij Idea debug mode. What should I do to interactive with the app in Intellij Idea debug mode?

[image]

Comment: Is it reproducible with any code?

Comment: I finally found the terminal input swith in Pycharm IDE @SergeyK.